# React native Amplify AWS package conflicting firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, react-native

In my react native project I earlier added aws amplify for push notification. After that I wanted to do analytics, so I added firebase to it. After that, my android app build but stops as soon as it launches.

I get error as

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service
>   com.amazonaws.amplify.pushnotification.RNPushNotificationMessagingService:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.amazonaws.amplify.pushnotification.RNPushNotificationMessagingService
>
> Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lcom/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService;
>           at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
>                 ... 10 more
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService

My ***app/build.gradle***

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libjsc.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libjsc.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project”
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        manifestPlaceholders = [
                appAuthRedirectScheme: 'com.project’
        ]
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation project(':react-native-reanimated')
    implementation project(':@react-native-community_netinfo')
    compile project(':react-native-charts-wrapper')
    compile project(':rn-fetch-blob')
    compile project(':react-native-wheel-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-pdf')
    compile project(':react-native-app-auth')
    compile project(':@aws-amplify_pushnotification')
    implementation (project(':react-native-device-info')){
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms" 
        exclude group: "com.android.support"
    }
    implementation project(':react-native-wheel-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':amazon-cognito-identity-js')
    implementation project(':@aws-amplify_pushnotification')
    implementation project(':react-native-app-auth')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    // Firebase dependencies
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9"
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
//com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to either use compile or implementation, not both. Remove these lines.

```
compile project(':react-native-wheel-picker')
compile project(':@aws-amplify_pushnotification')
compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
compile project(':react-native-app-auth')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set up AWS Amplify push notifications, you have to first set up a [Firebase project](https://console.firebase.google.com/) that AWS Amplify will hook into.

You can `Enable Google Analytics` in the Firebase project setup process.

Then include the line `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'` in `android/app/build.gradle`.

I've [created a walkthrough for the Firebase setup process for AWS Amplify](https://medium.com/@dantasfiles/setting-up-android-push-notifications-with-aws-amplify-e6334c6356d8), containing images for the various steps.